# Set value of a NSDictionary in a NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a dictionary as the value for another dictionary:

```
10 = {
        createdate = "2012-03-20 15:04:09.125177-05";
     }
```

I would like to set a value to the inner dictionary without having to pull it out, but

```
[NSDicionary setObject:forKey:]
```

only goes one deep. can I add another key to that? I tried

```
[[NSDicionary setObject:forKey:]forKey:]
```

but xCode didn't like that.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't set the value of an `NSDictionary` because it is immutable. You can only set the values of `NSMutableDictionary`. Actually, I suppose if you held a reference to the value of a dictionary and it referenced a mutable object, you could be sneaky and mutate it directly, even if it was being held in an immutable dictionary.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming that your dictionaries are mutable, you can use:

```
[[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"10"] setObject:newDate forKey:@"createdate"]];
```

To see how that works, note that it's equivalent to this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *innerDict = [someDictionary objectForKey:@"10"];
[innerDict setObject:newDate forKey:@"createdate"]];
```

If your dictionaries aren't mutable, you'll need to do more work. First, if the outer dictionary isn't mutable:

```
yourDictionary = [yourDictionary mutableCopy];
```

And if the inner dictionary isn't mutable:

```
NSMutableDictionary *newInnerDict = [[yourDictionary objectForKey:@"10"] mutableCopy];
[newInnerDict setObject:newDate forKey:@"createdate"]];
[yourDictionary setObject:newInnerDict forKey:@"10"];
```

Comment: worked like a charm. sorry for the late accept, got distracted with other code.  thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not modifying the outer dictionary, only the inner one, you need only one call to `setObject:forKey:`; the other call should be `objectForKey:`:

```
[[myDictionary objectForKey:outerKey] setObject:replacementValue forKey:innerKey];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSDictionary *innerDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:someDate forKey:@"createdate"];
[someOtherDictionary setObject:innerDictionary forKey:@"10"];
```

or, shorter:

```
[someDictionary setObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:someDate forKey:@"createdate"] forKey:@"10"]
```